# Prevent uploading large files on Opera Mini

Tags: javascript, nginx, form-submit, opera-mini

I have encountered a very interesting problem. We have switched from Apache to Nginx, and we have a file upload feature, which had a problem in Nginx. If the file to be uploaded is too large, then an error message is shown:

> **413 Request Entity Too Large**
>
> nginx/1.4.6 (Ubuntu)

This is caused by the fact that we have a limitation for file sizes, we do not accept files larger than 2 MB on the server. However, this is not a user-friendly error, so we wanted to hide the technical details and notify the user in a user-friendly way. I have implemented a feature which works for any browsers, except Opera Mini. I will take out some details from it, because they are irrelevant to the question:

```
if (isOperaMini()) {
    $("#opera-mini-photo-form").submit(function(e) {
        if (document.getElementById("opera-input").files[0].size >= 1048576) {
            e.preventDefault();
            alert"Invalid or too large file");
        }
    });
} else {
    //some code for other browsers
}
```

If the browser is Opera Mini, then the if inside the `submit` event will always be `false` and the `form` will always be submitted. I have checked the code written for Opera Mini in other browsers to see if something was implemented incorrectly. In other browsers it worked. I tried to alert the following value in Opera Mini:

```
document.getElementById("opera-input").files[0].size
```

The `alert` did not happen. Now, if we take into the account the fact that Opera Mini uses an Opera proxy to browse the web, I wonder whether the Javascript is actually running on the proxy server. If that is the case, it would explain why I am unable to check the file size. If not, then I do not know what could cause the issue. What should I use instead of

```
document.getElementById("opera-input").files[0].size
```

to check the size of the file?

Answer (score 1):

`document.getElementById("opera-input").files` is a File API.

File API is [not enabled](http://caniuse.com/#feat=fileapi) in Opera Mini.

Simple [`fiddle`](http://jsfiddle.net/x460Le3h/1/) to check.

So better to check file size on server and add error about file size to your response html.

Comment: Very nice answer, but the server responds with 403 if the file is too large, the request does not reach the source-code. This means that, according to your answer there is no solution, unless we change the server settings, which will not be done. If you can confirm that this is not possible without server setting change, then I will accept the answer. Is there an alternative?

Comment: You need to update your server limit and check size by server or you can make customize your 413 error page and add to it info about large file size.